# Any one help me code finish this by PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I have to make a program to teach children multipliers, this is the core code of the assignment.

```
#include <stdio.h>

  #define MIN       1
  #define MAXINDEX  10
  #define MAXTABLE  10
  #define STEP      1

 void main(void)
  {
    int i,j ;

    for (j = MIN; j <MAXTABLE; j += STEP)  {
        for (i = MIN; i <= MAXINDEX; i += STEP)
            printf(“%3d * %3d = %3d\n”, i, j, i*j);
        printf(“\n---------------\n\n”);
    }

    for (i = MIN; i <= MAXINDEX; i += STEP)
        printf(“%3d * %3d = %3d\n”, i, MAXTABLE, i*MAXTABLE);
 }
```

After I have to rewrite it to a next generation language so I designed to write it in python.
Like this

```
j=1
i=1
for j in range(1,11):
    for i in range(1,11):
        print('%3d * %3d =%3d' % (i, j, i *j))
    if j!=10:   
        print("\n---------------\n")
    else:
        print("\n")
```

And after that I have to make a UI for it so this image is what I designed to do like this [This is the design of me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuAJD.png)

Since I just study python for 3 days, so I try my best to write this:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import os.path
def Corecode():
    j=1
    i=1
    for j in range(1,11):
        for i in range(1,11):
            print('%3d * %3d =%3d' % (i, j, i *j))
        if j!=10:   
            print("\n---------------\n")
        else:
            print("\n")
from PySimpleGUI.PySimpleGUI import R, Image, Multiline
showrobot_column = [
    [sg.Image('E:\img\robot.png',size = (300,300))],
],
show_Textbox_selectbox = [
    [sg.Multiline(size=(50,20),key='-def-')],
    [sg.Listbox(values=['a','b','c','d'], enable_events=True, size=(50,20), key="")]

    ]


layout = [
    [sg.Column(showrobot_column),
    sg.VSeparator(),
    sg.Column(show_Textbox_selectbox)
    ]
]
window = sg.Window("First Test",layout)
while True:
    event, value = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
window.close()
```

I designed to make it like a robot is talking and let the children interact by buttonBut, but I find out I can't insert the image, and also I can't find a way to print the Multiplier table by the core code that on the front, so someone can help me to finish the code or tell me why the sg.image get error. TY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg


def corecode(base):
    return ("\n"+"-"*13+"\n").join([f'{i+1:>2d} * {base:>2d} = {(i+1)*base:>3d}' for i in range(10)])

sg.theme('DarkBlue3')
sg.set_options(font=("Courier New", 12))

showrobot_column = [
    [sg.Image('E:/img/robot.png', size = (300, 300))],
]

list_values = [f'{i+1:>2d}' for i in range(10)]
show_Textbox_selectbox = [
    [sg.Multiline(size=(15, 20), expand_y=True, key='-MULTILINE-')],
    [sg.Listbox(values=list_values, enable_events=True, size=(15, 10), key="-LISTBOX-")],
]

layout = [
    [sg.Column(showrobot_column),
     sg.VSeparator(),
     sg.Column(show_Textbox_selectbox),],
]

window = sg.Window("First Test", layout, finalize=True)
multiline = window['-MULTILINE-']
multiline.update(value=corecode(1))
listbox = window['-LISTBOX-']
listbox.update(set_to_index=0)
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == '-LISTBOX-':
        base = int(values[event][0])
        multiline.update(value=corecode(base))

window.close()
```

Comment: Almost all elements have a "default value" parameter. You can drop the lines between Window and while if using this in layout - `show_Textbox_selectbox = [[sg.Multiline(default_text=corecode(1), size=(15, 20), expand_y=True, key='-MULTILINE-')],
    [sg.Listbox(values=list_values, default_values=[list_values[0]], enable_events=True, size=(15, 10), key="-LISTBOX-")]]`

Answer (score 1):

This is a shameless small tweak to Jason's answer (choose his as it's correct).

Wanted to include a couple of capabilities that may be helpful to some.  One is that almost all elements have an initial value that you can set in your layout instead of finalizing it and then setting them.  It reduces code.

I'm also including a "Trinket" embedded in this answer as a test.  This way you can run the example on this StackOverflow page.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg


def corecode(base):
    return ("\n"+"-"*13+"\n").join([f'{i+1:>2d} * {base:>2d} = {(i+1)*base:>3d}' for i in range(10)])

sg.theme('DarkBlue3')

list_values = [f'{i+1:>2d}' for i in range(10)]

show_Textbox_selectbox = [[sg.Multiline(default_text=corecode(1), size=(15, 20), expand_y=True, key='-MULTILINE-')],
    [sg.Listbox(values=list_values, default_values=[list_values[0]], enable_events=True, size=(15, 10), key="-LISTBOX-")]]

layout = [
    [sg.Image(sg.EMOJI_BASE64_HAPPY_THUMBS_UP), sg.VSeparator(), sg.Column(show_Textbox_selectbox)]
         ]

window = sg.Window("First Test", layout, font='Courier 12')

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == '-LISTBOX-':
        base = int(values[event][0])
        window['-MULTILINE-'].update(value=corecode(base))

window.close()
```

Here is a link to the Trinket should it not embed correctly - https://trinket.io/pygame/d59ef3b352

```html
<iframe src="https://trinket.io/embed/pygame/d59ef3b352" width="100%" height="600" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```